# .desktop files: how to specify the icon path

Tags: icons, .desktop

I had a look at the .desktop files on my 12.04 Ubuntu system, and many of them do not have a full path specification for their icon file.  It is rather something like:

```
Icon=anjuta
```

or

```
Icon=vlc
```

or

```
Icon=application-x-clementine
```

Is there a common path where icons can be stored so that this can work ? If not, how does this work ? If I try to do the same thing with my own icons I have to specify the full path.

e.g.

```
Icon=/usr/local/share/my-icon.png
```

works fine, but

```
Icon=my-icon.png
```

will fail.

Any kind of help is welcome!

Answer (score 21):

Yeah the lookup is pretty complicated. Here are the [freedesktop icon specifications](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) on directory layouts:

> Icons and themes are looked for in a set of directories. **By default,
>   apps should look in $HOME/.icons (for backwards compatibility), in
>   $XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons and in /usr/share/pixmaps (in that order)**.
>   Applications may further add their own icon directories to this list,
>   and users may extend or change the list (in application/desktop
>   specific ways).In each of these directories themes are stored as
>   subdirectories. A theme can be spread across several base directories
>   by having subdirectories of the same name. This way users can extend
>   and override system themes.
>
> In order to have a place for third party applications to install their
>   icons there should always exist a theme called "hicolor" [1](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html). The data
>   for the hicolor theme is available for download at:
>   http://www.freedesktop.org/software/icon-theme/. Implementations are
>   required to look in the "hicolor" theme if an icon was not found in
>   the current theme.
>
> Each theme is stored as subdirectories of the base directories. The
>   internal name of the theme is the name of the subdirectory, although
>   the user-visible name as specified by the theme may be different.
>   Hence, theme names are case sensitive, and are limited to ASCII
>   characters. Theme names may also not contain comma or space.
>
> In at least one of the theme directories there must be a file called
>   index.theme that describes the theme. The first index.theme found
>   while searching the base directories in order is used. This file
>   describes the general attributes of the theme.
>
> In the theme directory are also a set of subdirectories containing
>   image files. Each directory contains icons designed for a certain
>   nominal icon size, as described by the index.theme file. The
>   subdirectories are allowed to be several levels deep, e.g. the
>   subdirectory "48x48/apps" in the theme "hicolor" would end up at
>   $basedir/hicolor/48x48/apps.
>
> The image files must be one of the types: PNG, XPM, or SVG, and the
>   extension must be ".png", ".xpm", or ".svg" (lower case). The support
>   for SVG files is optional. Implementations that do not support SVGs
>   should just ignore any ".svg" files. In addition to this there may be
>   an additional file with extra icon-data for each file. It should have
>   the same basename as the image file, with the extension ".icon". e.g.
>   if the icon file is called "mime_source_c.png" the corresponding file
>   would be named "mime_source_c.icon".

The full specifications are much more exhausti{ve,ng} than this but the crux of it is: there are set directories you can just stuff icons into and the desktop will find them. Which of those best applies to you depends on your problem and your patience :)

Answer (score 10):

If you put icons in `/usr/share/icons/` (for system wide) or in your home `~/.icons`, then you can use only the icon file name without the extension in the .desktop file. E.g.

```
Icon=vlc
```

If not, then you must to use the absolute path for the icon in the .desktop file. E.g.

```
Icon=/usr/local/share/my-icon.png
```

Comment: How long does it usually take for the OS to detect that you've updated or added an `Icon` entry to your `.desktop` file?

Comment: @FilBot3 if you run `gtk-update-icon-cache -f -t <path to icon theme>`, it should be detected immediately. See [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gtk-update-icon-cache.1.html). Some package managers detect new icons and run this command automatically so you don't have to

Answer (score 7):

I have experience with just emblems, not icons, but that should work:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.icons/hicolor/48x48/
```

put the icon in that directory, let's suppose it is `myicon.png`

```
cp  myicons.png $HOME/.icons/hicolor/48x48/
```

Add the description file:

```
gedit $HOME/.icons/hicolor/48x48/myicon.icon
```

with content:

```
[Icon Data]

DisplayName=myicon
```

and now your `Icon=myicon` line should work. It works with emblems if you put them in an "emblems" subdirectory:

[image: personalized emblem]

Thanks to @Oli now I know *why* it works :-)

Comment: No way i did not know about emblems, super answer. I was actually making a badged/emblemed png than setting it to that. This is great man thanks. Is it just ubuntu that supports emblem? or all linux builds?

Comment: @Noitidart: I think it's basically a File Manager thing. They work at least in `nautilus` and in  `thunar` (so in Ubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome, and XUbuntu; and in other distros using them). Never checked with the K-side.