# How to fix oversized icons on Dash?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, unity-dash, .desktop

When an icon is changed from its default for a personalized one, it turns to be bigger than normal on the dash. How to make they look normal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your terminal will take up less space.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Over time, several bug reports have been posted on the subject, like [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1404730), but the phenomenon seems to be kind of persistent over different Ubuntu (Unity) versions.

#### How to fix it

Although the issue seems to be related to the path to your icon, I cannot offer you any insight in what exactly causes the problem.

I do know how to fix it however:

1. Copy your custom icon to a directory from where you can set your icon [without using the path to the icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435603/desktop-files-how-to-specify-the-icon-path), like `/usr/share/pixmaps`. Copy the icon *including its extension*.
2. In your `.desktop` file, set the icon without path and *without extension*:

   ```
    Icon=custom_icon
   ```
3. Then ***log out and back in***

The result:

`Icon=custom_icon`

[image]

instead of:

`Icon=/path/to/custom_icon.png`

[image]