# Where should I put the application icon for the application menu?

Tags: icons

I've created an application entry for an app in `/usr/share/applications/`, just like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Sample Application Name
Comment=A sample application
Exec=/opt/application
Icon=application.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Application
```

I noticed that many apps's `Icon` part in `/usr/share/applications` was just a file name, like `application.png` in the sample above. I guessed it should be a relative path. So where did most apps store its icon? If I want to follow the rule, which path should I put my icon in?

Comment: there is a pretty good answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/435603/desktop-files-how-to-specify-the-icon-path/435612#comment567239_435612

Comment: meaning this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/435612/72216