# How to add .desktop icon under program list?

Tags: icons, deb

I created a deb file for ubuntu and I can add the program under Sound & Video. But when I try to add icon for it , it show no icon image . My dbr.desktop file content is :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
_Name=Insight Daisy Book Reader
_Comment=Read Daisy Talking Books
Exec=dbr
Icon=icon32x32.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;AudioVideo;
```

I put the image icon32x32.png on the same level as this file . 
The corresponding screenshot shown below (Insight Daisy Book Reader).
[image]

I am not included the image path not any where in configuration file.

Please advise how to add program icon image ..

Thanks
Anes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.desktop files: how to specify the icon path](http://askubuntu.com/questions/435603/desktop-files-how-to-specify-the-icon-path)

Comment: As far as it comes to icons: you either use full path *and* use the extension, *or* you use one of the paths as mentioned in the link (like `/usr/share/pixmaps`) and *don't* use the extension in the `.desktop` file.

Comment: @JacobVlijm : Tell specific, I need to add a new icon for it. How to move that file to /usr/share/pixmaps ? if that file need xpm ? if so please share how this line : Icon=icon32x32.png   , change to be?

Comment: To make a .deb installer is quite another story, and outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to type the location of your icon completely .  Example :

Icon=/usr/share/icons/example.png

You change the word /usr/share/icons with your icon directory.

Comment: Tell me How to move that specific icon to /usr/share/icons/dbr.png in the deb?

Comment: Ok , extract your deb file , enter into it , make sure there are "usr" directory .