# How to bundle Java App to associated .desktop file in Gnome/Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, gnome, java, desktop-environments

Sorry, bu I didn't find any solution yet. I have an executable jar file (JavaFx based app) which I can easy start from bash:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

I want this app to start from a side panel in Ubuntu, so I'm creating .desktop file and place it in /usr/share/applications directory. And it works out, I see my app in apps list, mark it as Favorite and it appears in the side-panel ready for quick-access. But when I run it Gnome creates another associated .desktop file (temporary) and put a dot under that instead of using mine.

So, how to bundle my app with .desktop file ? So, when I run my app I want Gnome to put a dot under the right .desktop file (from which I run it!!). For example, when running Visual Code or Intellij Idea I have a dot under them, even if I do it from bash. Really, I search for idea.desktop file, see which executable it use, go to that executable and just run it from bash and it links with idea's icon!

```
/snap/bin/intellij-idea-ultimate
```

Of course, I'm not sure if it's usual executable, but anyway how does it work ? I thought that the .desktop file is responsible for this linkage, but if I run executable from bash and gnome puts a dot under the right icon without need to be started from this icon...

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UnFf.png)

Any thoughts/hints are welcome.

Comment: i would suggest comparing the file permissions of the desktop file that you created and the permissions of the other desktop files already present in /usr/share/applications, they should be same.

Comment: also this might be happening because of missing icon and specifying icons for your applications in the .desktop files is pretty complicated, i would suggest this reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435603/desktop-files-how-to-specify-the-icon-path)